# Accessing microphone from a service on Glass

Tags: google-glass

I would like a service to access the microphone (and do some signal processing on it a bit like what the google music is doing to recognise songs)
Is there a public API for that ? can't seem to find it :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class in Android? That should do everything you need. You might also find the [waveform sample](https://github.com/googleglass/apk-waveform-sample) on the Google Glass GitHub page to be a useful example.

Keep in mind that recording audio from a **service** (as in a background service) might be dangerous since other applications could need the microphone for voice recognition and so forth. Using an immersion for this might be a better approach.